# Dynamic components in Next.js static site export

Tags: next.js

I'd like to use Next.js static site export, but I'd also like to have dynamic components within the templates so that a build wouldn't need to be done every time they change, for example, a 'navigation' component. From what I've read this doesn't seem possible? Are there any workarounds, aside from creating a separate client-side build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next is working on allowing for a combined static + SSR generated site, but they're not there yet. I see a few options currently:

1. You can export a static site, but have that static site make api calls, etc. So you can load your navigation or whatever via api calls. Benefit - no new build. Drawback - those links/that markup is not available to search engines and won't appear initially for users.
2. If you're using a CMS and CI system (eg, WordPress for content, Travis for CI), you can set up webhooks or functions in WordPress to fire and trigger a rebuild & deploy in Travis when your content changes.
3. Go full SSR. It still delivers a fully rendered "static" page to the browser, it's just not a static HTML file at build time but one at run time. This is your best option if you *need* to have your dynamic content rendered immediately for the user and don't want to build with every change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We've already opted for the first recommendation as it's the most flexible, in my opinion.

#2 we have a large number of posts so it wouldn't be a viable option to rebuild all those posts on change.

#3 we'd prefer to have static pages because from my understanding rendering static html is more performant than SSR.